# Dynamic service injection in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, dependency-injection

I use `Angular.js` `Services` to share some data between controllers like this:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
mainApp.service('CalcService', function(){
        this.square = function(a) { 
            //do something
         }
});

mainApp.controller('CalcController', function($scope, CalcService) {
      $scope.square = function() {
          $scope.result = CalcService.square($scope.number);
      }
});
```

It works, but as you can see, in the controller, I have to inject `CalcService` and use it inside my controller. My problem is that, i have many services and in some pages of my Application i need to inject a service dependency and in some pages i don't need!  if i write it there, in pages that i don't need, i get error because my controller is inside another file and i didn't load it. How i can overcome to this?

I want that i can set that injection in some cases. I need an If Else statement. Is this possible?

My Application structure is like this: i have a main App and some widgets that can attach to the page, but each page has different widgets, then i need too inject proper widget services in my main module. i have one main module and one main controlle, and many services inside other controllers. and each page has it's own widgets and controller. in main controller i have to see which widgets loades and then inject its service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject only when you need the service.

Here is controller where you have the service injected

```
mainApp.controller('CalcController',['$scope','CalcService',function($scope, CalcService) {
      $scope.square = function() {
          $scope.result = CalcService.square($scope.number);
      }
}]);
```

Here is controller where you don't have the service injected

```
mainApp.controller('Calc2Controller',['$scope',function($scope) {
          $scope.square = function(n) {
              $scope.result = n * n;
          }
    }]);
```

***Edit 1***

It looks like you are having services and controllers in same files. This is something wrong.

You can see services share data globally or encapsulate logic that can be reused. While controller are focus on specific template.

I suggest you to separate your services and controller using this structure.

```
App--
   -components
   -features
          - login
                -loginController.js
                -login.html
   -services
          - userService.js
          - loginService.js
   -libs
          - bootstrap.js
          - lodash.js
```

Since your services are independent now,you can share them with any controller. You can be selective where to use one service and where not to.

Comment: Yes but i have one main module and one main controller, and many services inside other controllers. and each page has it's own widgets and controller. in main controller i have to see which widgets loads and then inject its service